# table row in php are stuck

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying to get te rows right in my table somehow it's stuck,
I don't know why. the first table with "rekening" should be showing all the results from the table rekening in my database which works , but the second row "creditcards" is a bit stuck.

Here is my code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$database);
$rekening= mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM Rekening");
$cc= mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM Creditcard");

while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rekening)){

    $h.= "<tr><td>".$row1['rekeningNummer']."</td>";

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cc)){

        $rekeningID = $row2['rekening_ID'];
        $creditcard= mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM creditcard WHERE Rekening_ID = '$rekeningID'");

        while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($creditcard)){
            $h.= "<td><td>".$row3['creditcardNummer']."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the picture of my page :

https://gyazo.com/1fa963573fd5d07d50e5e8231bcd487c

and here the database : 
https://gyazo.com/dc71363640e0b6495e9a3504d0405365

Comment: *"but the second row "creditcards""* - `creditcards` or `creditcard`? Two different animals here.

Comment: Is it intentional to have the double "<td><td>" tags ? There should either be a closing tag between those two, or one of those should be removed.

Comment: use `mysqli_error($db)` on all the queries; what did that show?

Comment: @TurboPT ye I closed it but now I get this : gyazo.com/6da24429ab1f5a9b7a4312d39a63701a

Comment: @johnsmith:  I figured that one of those needed to likely be removed, but it's your handling so I'm not sure. You may need to update the code above to reflect the latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that You open a new `<tr>` tag everytime You get an result, but You don't close that tag. Opening și many tags but not closing them might be one of your problems.
Instead of this

```
$h.= "<tr><td>".$row1['rekeningNummer']."</td>";
```

You can use this

```
$h.= "<tr><td>".$row1['rekeningNummer']."</td></td>";
```

Comment: I closed the <tr> tag now it gets underneath each other image here : https://gyazo.com/6da24429ab1f5a9b7a4312d39a63701a